# Typescript new Date() - 'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to get the current time using `new Date()`:

```js
function getTime(): Date{
  const d = new Date()
  return d
}
```

But this gives error:

```
'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

What's the correct way to use `new Date()` with typescript?

Comment: That is the correct way. Did you import or overwrite `Date` somewhere in the same file?

Comment: Date has a constructor; in fact, Date is defined to be of [type DateConstructor](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L882). Your code looks right to me, and [it works on the Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQCowLaoBQCUAXIgCICGUqA3gFCKIQIDOUiAJogLyJioDuZSvgL1EAJ3QhxSdrQC+tIA). Perhaps you have a Date import or class that conflicts with the built-in one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I had a conflict, I was using  `new Date()` within my `Date` react component:

```js
const Date = (): JSX.Element =>{
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());


  function tick(): void {
    setDate(new Date());
  }

  return(
    <div>
     {date.toLocaleTimeString("en-IT", { hour12: true, timeStyle: "short" })}
    </div>
  )      

}

export default Clock;
```